# How to replace text contains'\n' with sed in macos 11.1

Tags: bash, macos

I want to replace the text '123\nabc' to 'qqq',This is my code:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/"123\\nabc"/qqq/g' `grep "123\\nabc" -rl /Users/111/Desktop/1234`
```

The '/Users/111/Desktop/1234' is text document path. But it has an error which called ' bad flag in substitute command: '/''.I donot know how to replace it,Who can help me.

Comment: One too many /s before the g at the end of the sed expression

Comment: Do '123\nabc', 's/"123\nabc"...' and "123\\nabc" all indicate the same string? Does each one mean a multiple line?

Comment: `brew install gsed` would make things a lot easier

Comment: I want to know if there is another way to solve it.And i will try gsed after a day.

Answer (score 1):

Use `perl`

```
perl -i -pe 's/123\\nabc/qqq/g' /Users/111/Desktop/1234
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
sed -i -e 's|123\\nabc|qqq|g' /Users/111/Desktop/1234
```

You can use | instead of /. and use \ instead of single \